# Passing a variable as an index with same string wont work

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, observable

I am unable to understand why this won't work. I am working in VueJS 2.

```
// This is in my data object. api_data is basically an original copy of data returned from api_call, later I use this to update my maps, etc
api_data: {}

console.log(api_data) // returns an observer object with a sub key 'Sindh'
console.log(name) // returns 'Sindh'
console.log(name == 'Sindh') // returns true
console.log(name === 'Sindh') // returns false
console.log('typeof', typeof name); // returns string
console.log('api_data', _this.api_data[name]) // returns undefined
console.log('api_data', _this.api_data['Sindh']) // returns data
```

Output of console.log(api_data) // after getting data from api call

[image]

Comment: Show some more code?

Comment: @Badgy like what?

Comment: Well we dont even know the api data, name is undefined

Comment: `name` isn't necessary a string, read about `===` op

Comment: console.log(name === 'Sindh') // returns false . so your name is not same type as 'Sindh'

Comment: @DennisVash updated my questions, please check

Comment: returns data? what data?

Comment: please provide more context to give conclusions. as in where is name declared. where are you checking the condition. what is the type of data that is getting inserted in api_data.

Comment: If you assuming that `_this.api_data[name]` should throw data then you should first know, what `name` variable has. Note: You are not assigning `name` variable as `"Hello"` string anywhere (you are just doing comparison of two types)

Comment: `console.log(name)` gives you what exactly (including any subtleties how your browser may style it)?

Comment: Does VueJS's observer object has anything to do with it?

Comment: Probably…!? A complete self-contained example would really help here. We can't reproduce neither `name` nor `api_data` here, so it's hard to say anything.

Comment: @deceze I can provide those two variables but I am not sure how providing api_data will help here. I did console.log on api_data it says its an observer object which is vuejs's reactivity object (I think) and it has two sub keys. Each of those keys is a region (Sindh, Punjab) and each key has further data for markers (lat/long)

Comment: Well, give us as much as you can here if you want us to solve this…

Comment: Where and how does the "name" variable being declared?

Comment: try this one, console.log('api_data', _this.api_data[name.toString()])